# Choose to Display Post Thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I noticed the website http://gawker.com/ does something cool with images in posts - some posts have a large featured image above the title, others have none and just have images in the content.

My best bet on how to achieve this in WordPress is to add `<?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?>` above the title and make a selectable option to display or not display the_post thumbnail in the post edit screen.  It would need to only apply to the post (and not the excerpt)... I'm not sure how I would create that option.  I would appreciate if anybody knows how this would be done, can direct me to a somewhat relevant tutorial, or has a better idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: in `twentyten` I believe there is an example of this. I believe it examines the featured images width and uses it up there if it exceeds `900` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is modified code from `twentyten` that does what you're looking for. Put this in `header` or wherever you want the image to run. See string `post-thumbnail` -- that is size. Make sure it is defined as `940 x 180` in `functions.php`

```
if ( is_singular() && current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' ) &&
        has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) &&
        ($image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'post-thumbnail' ) ) &&
        $image[1] >= 940 ) :
    // Houston, we have a new header image!
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID );
elseif ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="940" height="180" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

It falls back to `header_image` if that is set. Feel free to change sizes.

Comment: So here is what I put in my posts http://snippi.com/s/a5910gm and here is what I put in functions.php http://snippi.com/s/3vwjw1y - shouldn't this be pulling the image if it's over 940 x 180?  I have it setup and I'm getting nothing.

Comment: modifying answer

Comment: For some reason this isn't working in my theme - the images are not being pulled and I'm very curious as to why.  This is pulling from the featured image, correct?  I wonder if there's an easier way to make a "Display image if larger than" type of code.

Comment: Yep. You have thumbnail support enabled? And you have `post-thumbnail` image size defined as 940x180? Note that all of the conditions in the `if` statement must be met. Perhaps it is too strict. Try debugging a little, see if you can just echo `'hello world'` inside the if statement...work your way from there.

Comment: Where does the post-thumbnail image size need to be defined?  I've tried to define it in Settings > Media and in functions.php http://snippi.com/s/brzsxol but it still isn't working :-(

Comment: That looks correct in `functions`. Time to debug a little!

Comment: Not working and I can't figure this out.

Comment: So - I found if I remove post-thumbnail from the third line it will always display a thumbnail.  If I leave it, then it always displays whatever I have where <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="940" height="180" alt="" /> is in your code.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Try using [Force Regenerate Thumbnails] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/) to rebuild the thumbnails, ensuring that size has been created. That size was possibly defined after the image was already uploaded? Or redefined? Or define a new size with a different name altogether, and then run that plugin.

Comment: Okay, so when I do that it now shows the thumbnail on every post - even if the thumbnail is too small.

Comment: `$image[1]` is width. `$image[2]` is height. Maybe you need to compare each? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: I'm not sure how I accomplish that, but I'm starting to think this isn't the correct solution.

Comment: Please take overly long discussions to chat, comments aren't meant for extensive discussion.